# More elegant way to aggregate by date

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame

```
               time  power
0  2019-01-01 00:00    100
1  2019-01-01 01:00    102
2  2019-01-01 02:00    100
3  2019-01-02 00:00     99
4  2019-01-02 01:00     98
5  2019-01-02 01:00    102
```

and would like to aggregate power by date. There are two aggregate functions: std and average. So, I would like to obtain the following output

```
         date   avg_power  std_power
0  2019-01-01  100.666667   1.154701
1  2019-01-02   99.666667   2.081666
```

Here is the code producing this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

power_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['2019-01-01 00:00', '2019-01-01 01:00', '2019-01-01 02:00', '2019-01-02 00:00', '2019-01-02 01:00', '2019-01-02 01:00'],
    'power': [100, 102, 100, 99, 98, 102]
})
power_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(power_df['time'])

power_df['date'] = power_df['time'].dt.date

grouped_power_by_date = power_df.groupby('date').agg(**{
    'avg_power': pd.NamedAgg('power', np.mean),
    'std_power': pd.NamedAgg('power', np.std),
})

print(grouped_power_by_date.reset_index())
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to group by date without adding an additional 'date' column?
2. When I use `as_index=False` in `group_by` the output looks like:

> ```
> avg_power std_power
> 0 2019-01-01  100.666667
> 1 2019-01-02  99.666667
> ```

However I expected to get the output which I described above. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
power_df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(power_df.time).dt.date).agg(**{
    'avg_power': pd.NamedAgg('power', np.mean),
    'std_power': pd.NamedAgg('power', np.std),
})
```

o/p

```
             avg_power  std_power
time                             
2019-01-01  100.666667   1.154701
2019-01-02   99.666667   2.081666
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already did what you want. When I run `print(grouped_power_by_date.reset_index())` I get your intended output:

```
         date   avg_power  std_power
0  2019-01-01  100.666667   1.154701
1  2019-01-02   99.666667   2.081666
```

Comment: Yes, the code I shared produces th expected output. However, I don't understand why 

grouped_power_by_date = power_df.groupby('date').agg(**{
    'avg_power': pd.NamedAgg('power', np.mean),
    'std_power': pd.NamedAgg('power', np.std),
})

produced something different

Comment: The difference is the indexing. When you aggregate with ```.agg()``` the returned DataFrame is indexed by how you grouped the data (date in this instance), while the first is numerically indexed (0, 1 etc.)